# My question is in a select statement how do you return the RID along with the table data?

Tags: sql-server, index, query-performance, database-internals, dmv

I need your help with a concept I want to show developers, that concept is to help them understand *how SQL Server retrieves data from a table*.

In the event that a developer does not use a clustered index on a table I want to be able to show them the RID (*Row Identification number*) SQL Server uses to find the record.

So my question is in a select statement - how do you return the RID?

I know that you can use the following to find where SQL Server stores the data in the data file:

```
SELECT TOP(100) sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(%%physloc%%) AS [File:Page:Slot], *
FROM  [dbo].[Badges] ;
```

```
SELECT   TOP(100) *
FROM   [dbo].[Badges]
CROSS APPLY sys.fn_PhysLocCracker(%%physloc%%);
```

My question is:

In a select statement how do you return the RID alongside the table data?

Comment: your query already returns what is known as the RID or "bookmark" in SQL Server. This is just the `File:Page:Slot` - there isn't some other number